# Can't install perl modules with cpan

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the Text::Template module with cpan but get this when I run 'install Text::Template' from the cpan shell.

```
cpan> install Text::Template
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163, <IN> line 1.
'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
............................................................................DONE
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163.
'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
.Could not split line["┬0\cL²\cU\c?└'¸\cCé"]
Could not split line["cÌX'ÔÒ"├█\cP\cE?▀&Ù┌╠5Ó%â¥mþlýBô¶ñg▒R\cIØ\cT\cPÈ¸\cX."]
Could not split line["\cH·©s:░KÉþ\cC\c^Û{65j¼¸\cL"]
Could not split line["\cD│í¬ð\cP|:ü▒HôU▓┴Bú‗Ð\cZyÄ"]
Giving up parsing your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errorsReading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163.
'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
............................................................................DONE
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 163.
'-qdt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
.Could not split line["┬0\cL²\cU\c?└'¸\cCé"]
Could not split line["cÌX'ÔÒ"├█\cP\cE?▀&Ù┌╠5Ó%â¥mþlýBô¶ñg▒R\cIØ\cT\cPÈ¸\cX."]
Could not split line["\cH·©s:░KÉþ\cC\c^Û{65j¼¸\cL"]
Could not split line["\cD│í¬ð\cP|:ü▒HôU▓┴Bú‗Ð\cZyÄ"]
Giving up parsing your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errorsLockfile removed.
```

I'm using ActivePerl 5.28.1 64bit on Windows 10. The same problem occurs for all the packages I tried, including Log::Log4perl and Test::More.

Comment: How did you install ActivePerl ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland With ActiveState, I downloaded the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) instead of ActivePerl.

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate this by corrupting my `sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz` file.

Erase the files in the `C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules` directory and try again.

Comment: I tried this and got the same error. I managed to install the module using strawberry perl, so I think I'll use it instead.